# What is the exact birthdate of Kalki avatar going to be?

Tags: vishnu, avatars, astrology, kalki, panchang

Some [blogs](http://www.speakingtree.in/allslides/predictions-regarding-the-kalki-avatar) on internet write 'Kalki Avatar will born in next 50-100 years and He will kill all evil people on Earth in third world war'. How far is this true?

What do present day astrologers in India say about the birthday of the Kalki avatar? Do we have to wait another 4,27,000 years?

When will those planetary positions (of his birth) mentioned in Puranas happen? What do astrologers say about this?

Comment: Try to find Bhagwatpuran 12th chapter, Kalkipuran and Bhavishya Puran

Comment: There was no exact date of birth in those puranas. If you have any info on exact date of his arrival, please provide that info.

Comment: he says Vaivaistara Manu rule has ended but I don't think it ended. @KeshavSrinivasan  do you think present Manu has changed?

Comment: @AnilKumar No, of course not.  We're only in the 28th Mahayuga of the Vaivasvata Manvantara.  A Manvantara has 71 Mahayugas.

Comment: Just 5000 years passed into first pada of kaliyuga. So we have to wait 4,27,000 years before kalki avatar take place

Comment: Kalki avatar has taken birth already. I have experienced his powers and he is going to end the kalpa. How will that happen? All the materialistic world will be heated by sun and become liquid. The neuclear war will take place. All the people who are blind in materialistic world will die. ;)

Comment: @ParthTrivedi Kalpa?!! There is a lot of time left till the end of kalpa, I think you meant yuga.

Comment: His birth date probably coincide with my birthdate after 4 lakh years from now. Because of all the bad deeds i'm doing, he can't tolerate it and come to finish me off :)

Answer (score 2):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalki

In this it is stated that Kalki can only be the one whose Birthday/Tithi falls on Dvadasi of Sukla Paksha. This amounts to just 12 days per any given year furthermore as it can only be the day of the Lord Sri Maha Vishnu (Chaitra Dwadashi) this amounts to just one day each year or 100 days in the last century.

Indian astrologers have analysed Puranas extensively to try and foretell the time of birth of Kalki. The signs described in the Kalki Purana are as follows:

1.The moon will be in Dhanishtha nakshatra, Aquarius, suggesting he will be wealthy, acclaimed and swift in action and thought.

2.The sun will be in Swati, the nakshatra of the sword.

3.Jupiter will be in Purva Ashadha nakshatra, Sagittarius.

4.The Ascendant Lord will be in Purva Ashadha nakshatra, also Sagittarius, suggesting invincibility and early victory.

5.Saturn will be exalted in Libra, predicting a balance between justice and the sword.

6.Ketu, a five-headed snake god in navagraha, will be exalted in Scorpio, suggesting he will descend atop a great white steed.
The Puranas describe the date as twenty-one fortnights from the birth of Krishna, which itself falls on Janmashtami in August. This would put his descent at Vaishakha, between April and May. At this time, the father of Kalki is foretold to be overwhelmed by the incarnation of Godhead that he sees as his son. This places Kalki under the sun sign of Aries or Taurus.